# Node.js upload images to firebase storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to upload `files(images)` in my firebase cloud function. After reading many posts, I found that the only way that I can do this is to use `Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API`, and here is my code:

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
var bucket = storage.bucket('myBucketName');
var buffer = bufferRepresentMyImage;
// what next?
```

I found the following code from `GCP's API`:

```
bucket.upload(filename, (err, file) => {
    // code goes here
});
```

However, it doesn't seem like will work since it never ask for file's data, and instead, the `callback function` returns a `file`. Can anyone please show me how to upload `image` with `bucket`?

Comment: You should look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions

Answer (score 2):

The remote destination filename is included in the options param. `filename` in your example (and this answer) is the local filename path.

```
let options = {
        destination: fileNameOnDestinationBucket,
        metadata: {                   // (optional)
            metadata: yourCustomMetadata,
            contentType: 'image/jpeg' // (example)
        }
    };

// with Promise:
bucket.upload(filename, options).then((response)=>{
    ...
});

// with callback:
bucket.upload(filename, options, (err, metadata, response)=>{
....
});
```